TextKit2 : - Custom Attributes
I have added an custom attribute for a paragraph using the below method
textStorage.addAttribute(.customCase, value: "checkList", range: paragraphRange)


When I insert some text in between the text which contains the custom attribute, that text is not inheriting/propagating the custom attribute of existing paragraph text
Old Text : -      This is a test
New Text : -     This is "some new" a test
The inserted part is not getting the custom attribute of the old text, Can I know why it's happening, Is it some textKit2's behaviour.
